# Why are my NSLog statements wrapped in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, nslog

No matter how wide I make the output window, Xcode 4 seems to always wrap the NSLog output to the default width of the window. Is there an easy way to fix this?

```
2011-04-17 16:31:29.781 MyApp[415:707] rotation : 0.006139
2011-04-17 16:31:29.841 MyApp[415:707] Angle:-0.016967
     rollingX:0.918938
```

instead of

```
2011-04-17 16:31:29.781 MyApp[415:707] rotation : 0.006139
2011-04-17 16:31:29.841 MyApp[415:707] Angle:-0.016967   rollingX:0.918938
```

Here is the code:

```
float angle;
float rollingX;
...
NSLog(@"Angle:%f\t rollingX:%f",angle,rollingX);
```

Comment: Can you show the code, please?

Comment: Code added in the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a restriction of the console view - there just seem to be no tab positions defined after approx. 60 columns. So the next tab will just go to the next line. If you copy the output and paste it into another editor (i.e. TextWrangler), it will show up just fine, so the text is not hard wrapping.

You might file a bug on Apple's radar for this issue.